# CCActionRemove / addChild is not being manifested consistently in scheduled method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Please bear with me because I'm very new to OOP/ObjC/Cocos2d.

I have a method that is triggered every second like so: `[self schedule:@selector(eyelidsBlink:) interval:1.0];`

The `schedule` method is this:

```
-(CCTimer *) schedule:(SEL)selector interval:(CCTime)interval
{
    return [self schedule:selector interval:interval repeat:CCTimerRepeatForever delay:interval];
}
```

The method is below:

```
- (void)eyelidsBlink:(CCTime)dt{

    CCActionRemove *actionRemoveEyelidsNormal = [CCActionRemove action];
    [_whiteGuy_EyelidsNormal runAction:actionRemoveEyelidsNormal];

    _whiteGuy_EyelidsBlink = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"EyelidsBlink_iPhone4.png"];
    _whiteGuy_EyelidsBlink.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2,self.contentSize.height/2);
    [_whiteGuy_EyelidsBlink setScale:0.5];
    [self addChild:_whiteGuy_EyelidsBlink];

    CCActionRemove *remove_eyelidsBlink = [CCActionRemove action];
    [_whiteGuy_EyelidsBlink runAction:remove_eyelidsBlink];
    NSLog(@"Eyelids blinked");

    _whiteGuy_EyelidsNormal = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"EyelidsNormal_iPhone4.png"];
    _whiteGuy_EyelidsNormal.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2,self.contentSize.height/2);
    [_whiteGuy_EyelidsNormal setScale:0.5];
    [self addChild:_whiteGuy_EyelidsNormal];
}
```

I can see the first blink, but I can't see any others after that. My `NSLog` is printing in the console every second, so I know the `eyelidsBlink` method is being called.

Can anyone help me figure out why I can't see any blinks after the first? Let me know if you need more information, or if you can suggest any tests to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's practically no time for the blink sprite to be rendered because you remove it the instant it was added. You'd have to schedule another selector once, ie eyeLidsBlinkOff that runs 0.1 seconds later and hides the blink sprite.

Note: This code is very inefficient. Creating sprites is a relatively slow operation. Instead keep both sprites as children but set one sprite's visible property to NO. While blinking simply flip each sprite's visible flag. This will make the code a lot shorter too.

Comment: A-ha, brilliant. Will try this when I get home. Thank you very much.

Comment: I re-worked my code to reflect your suggestion, and it is running successfully, and much more smoothly as well. Thanks for your advice.